# How to display screen share video in full screen on remote participants using Twilio Programmable video?

Tags: javascript, twilio

I am creating a Audio/Video call feature with screen sharing in my web application, everything is fine only when we share screen, that is display just below of participants video. I want to display this screen share section in full width on remote side. **I also share screenshot as a reference**. Any body help me much appreciated.

Below code use for screen sharing

```
function shareScreenHandler() {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!screenTrack) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia().then(stream => {
                screenTrack = new Twilio.Video.LocalVideoTrack(stream.getTracks()[0]);
                /*console.log(screenTrack);               
                screenTrack.classList.add('screeShare');*/                
                videoRoom.localParticipant.publishTrack(screenTrack);                
                shareScreen.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-desktop fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#00cc00;"></i>';
                screenTrack.mediaStreamTrack.onended = () => { shareScreenHandler() };
                $('#remotemedia div video:eq(1)').addClass("screeShare");
            }).catch(() => {
                alert('Could not share the screen.');
            });
        }
        else {
            videoRoom.localParticipant.unpublishTrack(screenTrack);
            screenTrack.stop();
            screenTrack = null;
            shareScreen.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-desktop fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
        }
    };
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Magnus extremely sorry it was just happen due to wrong selection.

Comment: Is the issue that you are showing the screen share too small on the remote side? What is the code you are using to display the screen share?